# Free and torsion Group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Can you please explain torsion subgroup and free subgroup of free abelian group?

and also if $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group;

how is $G$ a direct product of free part and torsion part?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will probably be able to get a better answer if you are more specific about what you would like to know about these things (since I assume someone just repeating the definitions is not what you are looking for).

Comment: Ya I wanted the proof for direct product part.and definitions with example as i found it difficult to understand.

Comment: Free abelian groups are torsion free. Do you mean the torsion subgroup of an abelian group?

Comment: Yes.torsion subgroup of a finitely generated abelian group

Comment: The torsion elements form a subgroup. The quotient is torsion free and hence a direct sum of infinite cyclic groups, so you get a complement by taking inverse images of generators of the cyclic summands. But the complement is not unique.